# Visible lines but no idea where in the html or css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've a small problem by creating my website. Some `div` or `text element` show some lines by moving the mouse over it. 
they get invisible by clicking somewhere else. But I haven't define a border.

I do not know how to continue, may someone has a idea what that could be?

My website use bootstrap 4.0

[example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho33X.png)

Comment: The reason why you are getting downvoted is because you did not supply us with any code to recreate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try

```
text-decoration: none;
```

It is hard to guess the problem from your description.
You can also try inspecting that perticular div. Right click that div and select inspect element. There the browser will show you the css applied to that div or text.

Comment: Thank you, the problem has solved at the moment. I have tried to upload a testsite for you and I see that this problem only occurs when I deffine a background image. Whyever, I don't know.